# Jenkins gradle daemons can't seem to be re-used or cleaned up and crashes system after couple of consecutive builds

Tags: android, jenkins, jvm, continuous-integration, gradle-daemon

I've got Jenkins configured for running about 50 consecutive app builds, but somehow after a build or 7-10 the heap seems to get flooded, occasionally crashing my system.

The Jenkins console output would show me something like:

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 4 stopped Daemons could not be reused

And if i open the Task Manager (on Windows) i can see that Jenkins keeps starting similar 'Open JDK Platform Binary' processes (more than 15!), but can't seem to clean them up and this is what eventually causes occasionally a system crash, but most of the time the next build to not be able to succeed.
Giving me a console log message like:

> - What went wrong:
>     Unable to start the daemon process.
>     This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>     For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>     Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>     Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxHeapSize=4g -Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Gradle\gradle-5.5\lib\gradle-launcher-5.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.5
>     Please read the following process output to find out more:
>     Error occurred during initialization of VM
>     Unable to allocate 131072KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 4194304KB heap.
>     Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>     Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Does anyone know how to fix this?